# Detect when an autofill happens via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autofill

When a user creates an account on certain sites, it sometimes require the user's basic information such as name, email, and location. Chrome has the ability to autofill this form if the user had previously entered his/her information.

My question is: is it possible to detect/identify whether the page the user is visiting can be autofilled?

A naive solution would be to parse every page for forms that can be autofilled. But is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly? Every form CAN be autofilled, obviously, so the answer is YES to the question in your text.

The question in your headline is a much different one - HAS the form been auto-filled?

There is a pretty good approximation: if you check on load if there are any values in the form (that differ from the ones you sent), and there are, the user can't have filled them manually, obviously. So then you know that auto-fill has taken place.

On the other hand, it almost sounds as if you are looking for a generic solution not for your own site but for a browser extension you yourself want to write? In that case the solution is the same though, immediately on page load look at the values the page provides and see if the ones actually there differ. I'm not exactly sure, but the onload event should be fine, I *think* autofill doesn't happen before the page has loaded. Maybe you'll even need to add a few hundred milliseconds on top of the onload event. The user can't type much anyway in less than a second, or select checkboxes etc., so it's still a very good guess.

Anyway, even after re-reading your headline and your question I'm actually MORE confused about what exactly you want to achieve - but as Douglas Adams wasn't the first one to try to teach us, often it's not the answer but the question itself that is the problem :)

Comment: sorry, the title is pretty bad. I'm not even sure autofill is the correct term here (maybe prefilled forms). When you create an account that requires basic info, you can sometimes click on one of the input boxes to fill out the entire form. Usually the form is not autofilled, thats why I can't use the method you mentioned. I am writing an extension that requires me to detect whether a form "can" be prefilled.

Comment: I still don't get it: what is your special requirement for "form CAN be autofilled", I mean, *ANY* form CAN be autofilled after all? I realize the question may be the answer you are looking for, but I already pointed that out :)

Comment: Rethinking the issue, maybe what you mean is that when the browser has more than one value for a (login) textfield it leaves it empty, but when you press arrow-down there is a popdown and you can select one of the values. Once you've done that the browser also fills out the password field with the pw matching the login-string you just selected.
If you want to find out if the browser indeed HAS such values for a field, but waits for the user to open that popdown menu, the answer is: There is no way to detect this from within a page's Javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can check for the default value `value="VALUE"` has changed
i.e:

`if (getElementById('inputID').value != 'VALUE') { // DO SOMETHING }`

or

check if value has changed:

`input type="text" onchange="alert('changed')">`

one of these two should help you ( i hope :)  )

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:-webkit-autofill');
```

to get all elements autofilled.

Then you just have to check if any new elements is in there in a loop.